# Unexpected font displayed in Android browser (Chrome and Firefox) when rendering a web page

Tags: android, html, browser, fonts

I have a web page that is displaying an unexpected font. I need the font to be displayed as Arial, and the computed font family for the text is "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" (as expected)

But when rendered on some android phones (not all) either using emulators or real devices, the font appears as a handwritten style font (unknown to me).

My question would be: Why is this font being used and how can I override it to display basic arial? I'm attaching a couple screenshots, one for the displayed font and another one for the computed styles I see when using dev tools on an emulator.[screenshot of emulator and computed style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9KQw.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yep I realized that I wasn't giving enough info when I found the issue. I was totally convinced that the issue was related to a default font on Android OS as I've seen this same font appearing randomly in different websites. Anyhow it's solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It seems that the guys at fontcdn have a weird configuration when importing Arial font. The code they provide asks to import this:

https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/arial-2

But when opening that link, the full import code is:

```
@font-face{
font-family:arial;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:900;
src:local('Arial'),url(https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/59002/Lalithabai.woff)
format('woff')
}
```

Which was loading this weird font Lalithabai everywhere. I've reported the issue to cdnfonts.com.